# Is it possible to set the position of a Java CharBuffer?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

A bit of backfill on what I am trying to do.

I want to parse a String, but to be able to compare, for example

- 1 char at position x
- 2 chars at position x
- ...
- n chars at position x

failing that

- 1 char at position x+1
- 2 chars at position x+1
- ...
- n chars at position x+1

etc

continuing until I get a match, or EOS.

It's easy to do this with an array but I want to do this in a method and return a buffer with an index pointing to the next place to start processing. I was led to believe CharBuffer was a good solution for this, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT** by way of an example - not exactly compile-able code!

Main

```
List template1 = new List();
List template2 = new List();
String exampleInput = "oneone two";

template1.add ( "one" );
template1.add ( "two" );
template1.add ( "three" );

template2.add ( "one" );
template2.add ( "one" );
template2.add ( "two" );

Set templates = new Set();
templates.add ( template1 );
templates.add ( template2 );

NoisyParser np = new NoisyParser();
np.parse( templates, exampleInput );
```

NoisyParser

```
void parse( Set templates, Sting inp ){
     iterate over each template that matches inp{
        find_match( template, inp );
     }
}

boolean find_match( template, inp ) {
    This is where I need the magic to work out if the current element
    in template matches the current position of inp, or inp+1, give or take.
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? Compare two Strings and find the first position where they mismatch? Or compare n Strings?

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated, I have a number of lists of strings that I want to match against a noisy input string to see which  list matches, is any.

Comment: I think it'd be best if you provided a small example. Say, one list with two strings, another list with three strings and the input string, then specify what exactly you're expecting the result to be. Your exact requirements are somewhat hard to understand from the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CharBuffer` has an internal index from which you can do relative reads from, so yes, that should fit your criterias.

You set the position using the (inherited) [`Buffer.position(int newPosition)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28int%29) method.

You can also `mark` a position, and `reset` to the previous mark.

---

Since classes from the NIO package usually are used for (and ment to be used for) I/O, I encourage you to consider wrapping up a `char[]` and an `int pos` in class:

```
class PositionableCharArray {
    int pos;
    char[] chars;

    ...
    public void setPos(int pos) { ... }
    public char readChar() { return chars[pos++]; }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't he just reuse `java.text.ParsePosition`? Sounds like that's made for exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, isn't your PositionaleCharArray and a CharBuffer going to be the same thing for the way I want to use them?

Comment: Possibly. The `PositionableCharArray` would have a much smaller interface, which makes it easier to ensure that some invarians hold (`chars` never changes, 0 <= `pos` < `chars.length` and so on...). What if you for instance pass a `CharBuffer` to some future method, which thinks it's convenient to `clear` the buffer. Also, since that class would have a clearer purpose it would ease up on reading the code and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could implement this using `Buffer.charAt(int)` to get characters relative the current position, and `Buffer.get()` to advance the current position. Or you could use the `Buffer` operations for manipulating the position.

But I think you'd be better of implementing your own class that reads the characters into an `char[]` (or a `String`) and provides methods to perform the primitive operations that you need.  You *may* get a more performant solution using `CharBuffer`, but the chances are that this won't be the performance bottleneck.

Comment: Cheers, that seems to be the consensus. I probably would have ended up trying to shoehorn a Buffer into what I wanted.